# Chromedriver disable window auto expand

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having issues with working with a lot of chromedrivers in parallel. The issue is very simple, when page is loaded and some custom JS is executed, this page becomes at the top of the screen. I don't want the page to be focused and expanded to desktop each time particular chromedriver loads a page and executes javascript.
I want all of them be always hided.

Is there any chrome capability that prevents this?
I read thrice through http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if anyone is intersted. After adding following lines it started work (c#)

```
options.AddArgument("--disable-blink-features");
options.AddArgument("--disable-app-list-dismiss-on-blur");
options.AddArgument("--disable-core-animation-plugins");
```